# Find out next <td> id by clicking on a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a some td's like this

```
<td id="first">first</td>
<td id="second">second</td>
<td id="third">third</td>
<td id="fourth">fourth</td>
```

By clicking on one td I want to find out the id's of its next two tds.
When I click on 'first' I need to get 'second' and 'third' values.

How can I achieve this using JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: What if you click on the fourth one? Then there are no next two.

Comment: I suggest starting with the jQuery [tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/?rdfrom=) and [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery

This will alert 'undefined' if you click on the last cell.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3QxF/)

```
$('td').click(function () {
    alert($(this).next().attr('id'));
});
```

### JavaScript

This method is a bit hacky because .nextSibling returns a text node object (not a node) which doesn't contain an `id` property. It gets a list of siblings from its `parentNode`, we then iterate over them until we get a match, the next index is the next sibling.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qb253/)

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].onclick = function () {
        var siblings = this.parentNode.children;
        var i = 0;
        while (siblings[i] != this) { i++; }
        if (i < siblings.length)
            alert(siblings[i + 1].id);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next(`) twice. You will have to check if next has brought an element or not as for second last you wont get second and for last you wont get first and second next element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yJxsY/)**

```
$('td').click(function () {
    first = $(this).next('td');
    second = first.next('td');
    if (first.length) alert(first.text() );
    else alert("No next");

    if (second.length) alert(second.text());
    else alert("No next");
});
```

Comment: Between two tds there are hidden input fields. When I use next() it is giving input field's id. How to get next td's id? Sorry I didn't mentioned about hidden fields in my question.

Comment: Not given in OP, Can you make fiddle with that?

Comment: `Between two tds there are hidden input fields.` not a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has sibling selectors and functions that you can use for this:

http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next().attr('id');
    if (id) alert(id);
});
```